# configure WSO2 Web Services Framework for C++ (WSO2 WSF/C++) on windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, web-frameworks, wso2

i use this documenet for configure on windows [WSO2 Web Services Framework for C++](http://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/2.0.0/docs/) 
form the following documnet i able to start axis2_http_server and it's running on port on 9090 
its display deployed application on http://localhost:9090/axis2/services 
but when i try to create hello.cpp sample application from the given documentation but not able to compile the hello.cpp src file

i install all listed Dependencies on my windows 7 box then also not able to compile hello.cpp i install visual c++ 2008 and also try with cygwin for gcc compiler then also not able to compile can any one help to set development environment for WSO2 Web Services Framework for C++ on windows

Answer (score 0):

Try using visual studio to build a project. Another option is to try and look at the samples makefile shipped with wsf/cpp and use a similar command.